# SIP Servlet Container Scalability test

Tags: sip, scalability, sip-server, sip-servlet, mobicents-sip-servlets

I'm gonna to have a scalability and performance test on SIP Servlet Container. what I want to do is to measuring the memory consumption and response time based on the deployed Servlets on the Container. Unfortunately I'm not so experienced in SIP Servlet programming, hence I appreciate any help in advance. 
My scenario is as follows:

We have a SIP Servlet Container, and a Client which invokes servlets in container(sending SIP messages and receiving response).

On the other hand, we have a generator which deploys X number of servlets in each iteration on the container.

Then in each iteration, the client sends a request to the container and invokes an application(Servlet(s)) and receives a response.

The aim of this test is to test performance of container based on deployed servlet on it. It means that in each iteration the number of deployed servlets on the container is increased.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are not here to write your code. Please add a [mcve] detailing the code you've written. Write why it is not working and what the result should look like.

Comment: Hi Adriaan. I only have the scenario. I want to know how it's possible to do this measurement. Actually, I am not looking for a peace of code, I'm trying to know the way that we can do this measurement.